# Why does a LED light up in reverse direction at a DC generator worked by a falling object

Tags: electric-current, free-fall, light-emitting-diodes

I have done the following experiment:

A DC generator is worked by an object falling and connected to the DC generator via string. The DC generator is coupled to a LED in reverse direction.

The observation was the following:

As long as the object falls, the LED is off. When the objects hits the floor, the LED very shortly lights up.

Why is that? It seems to be a [Reverse-recovery effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Reverse-recovery_effect) but in the opposite direction.

Comment: Are you sure there's no inductance in the motor which causes a back-EMF when the rotor suddenly stops?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It's a generator, not a motor. And of course there is an inductance in it.

Comment: Generator and motor are identical-just a question of whether VI --> mechanical work or the other way around

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Can you describe your DC generator?

Comment: @garyp No, I'm sorry. I'm not near that generator anymore. It looked very simple, so maybe just an alternator with a rectifier or a dynamo.

Comment: Was there a capacitor in the circuit?

Comment: @BMS There might be a capacitor insinde the DC generator, but there wasn't one as a separate piece in the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Your diode is acting as a [Flyback Diode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode), also called an "inductive kickback" diode.

When current is flowing through the inductor (motor, generator, etc), a magnetic field is maintained.  When the circuit is no longer excited the field collapses, which acts to oppose the *change* in current.  This created a voltage spike ("inductive kick") on the previously-negative side of the inductor.

The LED is the easiest path for current to flow, to alleviate the high voltage.  What you are seeing is the inductive kick being snubbed by that LED.

In electronics, any time you are switching an inductive load, you need to put these diodes in place.  The kick can (and will) destroy transistors, MOSFETs, and even relays contacts.  Usually you use a Schottky diode, because of the lower forward voltage.  But then you can't see it light up :)

Comment: holymoley I was right! :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes sir :)

Comment: OK. But there shouldn't be any (large) current flowing, because the diode is in reverse direction. So the circuit is effectively opened. A voltage is induced in the inductor by a changing magnetic field, but it can't create a current. So, when the magnetic field stops changing (because the object hit the floor), the induced voltage stops. As there is no current, there shouldn't be any Back-EMF.

Comment: @Toscho Ah, but the voltage being created by the collapsing magnetic field is in the reverse polarity of the voltage that the generator has been producing. In other words: The spike is on the (previously) negative side of the diode. When the generator is operating, the generated positive voltage is applied to the diode's cathode, and so no current flows through the diode. But, when the generator stops, the induced voltage brings the diode's anode to a higher potential than the cathode.  So, for a moment, current will flow through the diode in a "normal" way, that is, from anode to cathode.

Comment: @bitsmack But why is the magnetic field collapsing? It just stops changing, afaics.

Comment: @Toscho The magnetic field in a DC generator induces current in just one direction.  This field (and current) may pulse, or may be fairly constant, depending on the generator. When the external driving force is removed, this field is what collapses.  You are correct, in that it stops changing. But if there is any non-zero field being generated at the time that it stops, this field is what collapses to zero, and creates the induced current.  Does this make sense?  I'll give some though to explaining it better, and then I'll update the answer.  But it might be a few days :)

Comment: @bitsmack The simplest form of a generator is a coil rotating inside or around a permanen magnet's static magnetic field. If the rotation stops, the magnetic field still exists. Why should it collapse?

Comment: @Toscho Sorry for the long delay! To answer your question: we aren't talking about the permanent field set up by magnets, but instead the magnetic field which is created when current flows through a coiled wire.  In the case of DC, this field doesn't change as long as the current is constant, and this field "goes away" when the current stops. A good example is when you wind wire around a nail and hook it up to a battery. This electromagnet only functions when current is flowing; if you remove the battery, the field collapses and the magnetism goes away...